# Proof Of Authority Consensus and one authority getting hacked

Tags: consensus

What could happen if an authority (validator) gets hacked in a PoA consensus?

Would it be able to block the system as it won't be able to mine its block?

Answer (score 2):

In reality it depends on the algorithm, as PoA is more of a family of consensus algorithms that run on the same concept of authorized block producers, but generally no. If a block producer misses their turn to produce a block, they're skipped.

Comment: so there is a time limit for the selected validator to produce a block? in Clique PoA?